# React Native Warning on screen transition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to move to another screen based on some conditions from my render view in react native

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
}

render(){

  if(this.state.num == "yes"){
    return(this.props.navigation.navigate("Homepage"))
  }
  else{
     return null;
  }

}
```

}

This works by moving me to the next screen thus the `Homepage` but it gives a warning.

`ReactNativeJS: Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.`

Is there a way to resolve this warning. I would be grateful to know. Thanks

Comment: `constructor(props) { super(props); }` maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try running that logic within the `componentDidUpdate` method, which is run after render